# How to remove SyntaxToken when using a Code Fix Provider

Tags: c#, abstract-syntax-tree, roslyn

I'm working on a code base which has the purpose to format code. In some instances, I have to remove syntax tokens such as the keyword "params" inside the parameter list if I found one and it's redundant or remove some unneeded braces ( "{" "}").

The thing is, it's so hard and uneasy to remove syntax token from the syntax tree. I have tried many different solutions that you can find below, but for the life of me, I cannot succeed. I'd like a solution that could work for any syntax token U might encounter and that I need to possibly remove from the syntax tree.

In the following case, I have built an analyzer that is currently functionnal but the code fix provider is not quite working... (It's a case of redundant params keyword usage).

//UPDATE - I have provided full code of Analyzer/Code fix provider / NUnit tests

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeFixes;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Formatting;

namespace RefactoringEssentials.CSharp.Diagnostics
{
    [ExportCodeFixProvider(LanguageNames.CSharp), System.Composition.Shared]
    public class RedundantParamsCodeFixProvider : CodeFixProvider
    {
        public override ImmutableArray<string> FixableDiagnosticIds
        {
            get
            {
                return ImmutableArray.Create(CSharpDiagnosticIDs.RedundantParamsAnalyzerID);
            }
        }

        public override FixAllProvider GetFixAllProvider()
        {
            return WellKnownFixAllProviders.BatchFixer;
        }

        public async override Task RegisterCodeFixesAsync(CodeFixContext context)
        {
            var document = context.Document;
            var cancellationToken = context.CancellationToken;
            var span = context.Span;
            var diagnostics = context.Diagnostics;
            var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);
            var diagnostic = diagnostics.First();
            var node = root.FindNode(context.Span) as ParameterSyntax;
            if (node == null)
                return;

            if (!node.Modifiers.Any(x => x.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ParamsKeyword)))
                return;

            var oldParameterNode = node;
            var paramList = node.Parent as ParameterListSyntax;
            if (paramList == null)
                return;

            //var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(
            //                            oldParameterNode.Parent as ParameterListSyntax,
            //                            paramList.WithParameters
            //                            (SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(paramList.Parameters.ToArray()))
            //                            .WithLeadingTrivia(node.GetLeadingTrivia())
            //                            .WithTrailingTrivia(node.GetTrailingTrivia()))
            //                            .WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation);

            //var paramsKeyword = (node.Modifiers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ParamsKeyword)));
            //var indexParams = node.Modifiers.IndexOf(paramsKeyword);
            //var syntaxListWithoutParams = node.Modifiers.RemoveAt(indexParams);
            //node.ReplaceToken(paramsKeyword, syntaxListWithoutParams.AsEnumerable());
            context.RegisterCodeFix(CodeActionFactory.Create(node.Span, diagnostic.Severity, "Remove 'params' modifier", token =>
            {
              var newNode = SyntaxFactory.Parameter(node.AttributeLists,node.Modifiers.Remove(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.ParamsKeyword)),node.Type,node.Identifier,node.Default);
             var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(node, newNode);
             return Task.FromResult(document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot));
            }), diagnostic);
            //context.RegisterCodeFix(CodeActionFactory.Create(node.SKCpan, diagnostic.Severity, , document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot)), diagnostic);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the use cases in my situation.

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using RefactoringEssentials.CSharp.Diagnostics;

namespace RefactoringEssentials.Tests.CSharp.Diagnostics
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class RedundantParamsTests : CSharpDiagnosticTestBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestBasicCase()
        {
            Analyze<RedundantParamsAnalyzer>(@"class FooBar
{
    public virtual void Foo(string fmt, object[] args)
    {
    }
}

class FooBar2 : FooBar
{
    public override void Foo(string fmt, $params object[] args$)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(fmt, args);
    }
}", @"class FooBar
{
    public virtual void Foo(string fmt, object[] args)
    {
    }
}

class FooBar2 : FooBar
{
    public override void Foo(string fmt, object[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(fmt, args);
    }
}");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestValidCase()
        {
            Analyze<RedundantParamsAnalyzer>(@"class FooBar
{
    public virtual void Foo(string fmt, object[] args)
    {
    }
}

class FooBar2 : FooBar
{
    public override void Foo(string fmt, object[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(fmt, args);
    }
}");
        }

        [Test]
        public void ValideParamsUsageTests()
        {
            Analyze<RedundantParamsAnalyzer>(@"class FooBar
{
    public virtual void Foo(string fmt, params object[] args)
    {
    }
}

class FooBar2 : FooBar
{
    public override void Foo(string fmt, params object[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(fmt, args);
    }
}");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestDisable()
        {
            Analyze<RedundantParamsAnalyzer>(@"class FooBar
{
    public virtual void Foo(string fmt, object[] args)
    {
    }
}

class FooBar2 : FooBar
{
    // ReSharper disable once RedundantParams
    public override void Foo(string fmt, params object[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(fmt, args);
    }
}");
        }
    }
}
```

For those who might be interested in how I determine that the params is redundant, here's the logic:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Linq;

namespace RefactoringEssentials.CSharp.Diagnostics
{
    [DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
    public class RedundantParamsAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
    {
        private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor descriptor = new DiagnosticDescriptor(
            CSharpDiagnosticIDs.RedundantParamsAnalyzerID,
            GettextCatalog.GetString("'params' is ignored on overrides"),
            GettextCatalog.GetString("'params' is always ignored in overrides"),
            DiagnosticAnalyzerCategories.RedundanciesInDeclarations,
            DiagnosticSeverity.Warning,
            isEnabledByDefault: true,
            helpLinkUri: HelpLink.CreateFor(CSharpDiagnosticIDs.RedundantParamsAnalyzerID),
            customTags: DiagnosticCustomTags.Unnecessary
        );

        public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics => ImmutableArray.Create(descriptor);

        public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
        {
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(
                (nodeContext) =>
                {
                    Diagnostic diagnostic;
                    if (TryGetParamsDiagnostic(nodeContext, out diagnostic))
                    {
                        nodeContext.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
                    }
                },
                SyntaxKind.ParameterList
            );
        }

        //I think it's a better decision to head in this direction instead of MethodDeclaration.
        private static bool TryGetParamsDiagnostic(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext nodeContext, out Diagnostic diagnostic)
        {
            diagnostic = default(Diagnostic);
            if (nodeContext.IsFromGeneratedCode())
                return false;

            var paramList = nodeContext.Node as ParameterListSyntax;
            var declaration = paramList?.Parent as MethodDeclarationSyntax;

            if (declaration == null)
                return false;

            if (declaration.Modifiers.Count == 0 || !declaration.Modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.OverrideKeyword))
                return false;

            var lastParam = declaration.ParameterList.Parameters.LastOrDefault();
            SyntaxToken? paramsModifierToken = null;
            if (lastParam == null)
                return false;

            foreach (var x in lastParam.Modifiers)
            {
                if (x.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ParamsKeyword))
                {
                    paramsModifierToken = x;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!paramsModifierToken.HasValue ||
                !paramsModifierToken.Value.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ParamsKeyword))
                return false;

            diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(descriptor, lastParam.GetLocation());
            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious how you determine that the `params` keyword is redundant?

Comment: Please see update, I've added how I get it done. If you have questions about it, I'd like to clarify. I'm using the old code base from NRefactory and porting it with the Roslyn platform. The logic in code analysis was already there, I just had to update it. Moreover, the code fix provider part, that's on me. @DavidG

Comment: Can you provide us with the full code for the analyzer/codefix/tests? It's easier to play around with instead of having to recreate it ourselves.

Comment: So Roslyn will let you hack at the trees using ReplaceNode or Remove node, but you have to keep track of all the details? Yuk.  See if you can't find a (non-Roslyn) source-to-source transformation system; you could then then write a s-to-s transform like  **rule remove_params(v: visiblity, r: type, n: identifier, a1: arg, a2:arg): " \v \r \n(\a1, params \a2)" --> " \v \r \n(\a1, \a2)"** .  This means you don't have to do all that low-level node hacking.

Comment: @IraBaxter It has to be Roslyn. I kind of understand oyur point of view, but never having to use such a thing, I cannot fully appreciate your advice. I'm working on a library that wants to update their codebase using the Roslyn platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you don't want to remove the whole node, rather you just want to remove the `params` modifier.  Since `SyntaxNodes` are immutable, you need to create a new node with the appropriate modifiers using the `WithModifiers` method:

```
public async override Task RegisterCodeFixesAsync(CodeFixContext context)
{

    var diagnostic = context.Diagnostics.First();
    context.RegisterCodeFix(CodeAction.Create("Remove 'params' modifier", async token =>
    {

        var document = context.Document;
        var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(token);

        var fullParameterNode = root.FindNode(diagnostic.Location.SourceSpan, false) as ParameterSyntax;

        // Keep all modifiers except the params
        var newModifiers = fullParameterNode.Modifiers.Where(m => !m.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ParamsKeyword));
        var syntaxModifiers = SyntaxTokenList.Create(new SyntaxToken());
        syntaxModifiers.AddRange(newModifiers);

        var updatedParameterNode = fullParameterNode.WithModifiers(syntaxModifiers);

        var newDoc = document.WithSyntaxRoot(root.ReplaceNode(fullParameterNode, updatedParameterNode));
        return newDoc;
    }, "KEY"), diagnostic);
}
```

As for a generic remove option for syntax, I don't know of one that is easy to use.  The `Node.ReplaceSyntax` is a rather complicated method and I usually find it easier to work with the `ReplaceNode` or `RemoveNode` methods.

Comment: You sir, are a King :-) 
It took me so much time to come up with those three solutions :O
Thank you so much ! :-D

Comment: If it's not too much asking
How would you create a code fix for a situation where you have an ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax and the "()" tokens are redundant there so, they should be eliminated ? 
From
            var x = new TestClass()
            {
                Prop = 1
            };
To
            var x = new TestClass
            {
                Prop = 1
            };
@JohnKoerner

Comment: I'd have to play around with it to get it working.  There is no magic here.  I usually just take a best guess at what to register for and then set my breakpoints and inspect the state of the nodes I have.  At that point I determine what I can manipulate to get the result I want.

Comment: @KevinAvignon Take a look at this blog post and see if it answers your questions, if not, ask a new question and I'll try and answer it: https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/a-codefix-that-removes-redundant-parentheses/

Comment: I might have another question for you  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972748/removing-and-adding-content-with-code-fix-provider 
Thanks !